# NSMutableArray, add sprite and remove last object (last added sprite)?

Tags: cocoa, cocos2d-iphone

```
-(void)createSprite{

CCSprite *shotV = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"green.png"];

[self addChild:shotV z:1];

[shotVArray addObject:shotV];
NSlog(@"%@",shotV);

}     
-(void)aSpecialCase{

[self removeChild:[shotVArray lastObject] cleanup:YES];

}
```

I'm not getting this to work.
The function "createSprite" spams out sprites. "In aSpecialCase" I want to remove the last sprite that was created. Also hoping that removing it will end the current CCSequence for that instance.

Comment: Hi, first of all, I fixed a minor bug with the array. Now it's working. The object gets added and removed. But after removing it (calling aSpecialCase), the function "createSprite" don't creates any more sprites when called.

Comment: OK, but what happens instead? What's the value of `shotV` after the first line? What, if anything, happens with `shotVArray`? Do you get any output in the Console?

Comment: (
    "<CCSprite = 12299C70 | Rect = (0.00,0.00,70.00,70.00) | tag = -1 | atlasIndex = -1>",
    "<CCSprite = 12273010 | Rect = (0.00,0.00,70.00,70.00) | tag = -1 | atlasIndex = -1>"
)
This is what I'm getting after hitting my button 2 times. I can remove it, everything works except this line:
[self removeChild:[shotVArray lastObject] cleanup:YES];
The program dose not shut down, and I don't getting any errors.
I have a NSlog(@"%@",shotH); don't give me anything after the "aSpecialCase" has been exicuted.

Comment: Where did you put that `NSLog` statement? Also, what's `shotH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)aSpecialCase{
[self removeChild:[shotVArray lastObject] cleanup:YES];
}
```

This only removes the sprite from layer.. Doesn't remove it from array itself...

So better way is..

```
-(void)aSpecialCase{
  CCSprite *sprite  = [pshotVArray lastObject];
  [self removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];
  [pshotVArray removeObject:sprite];
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)